# How do I Import/export from/to an excel file in .net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, import, export

I would like to do both import from and export to, separately.
the import would get the data from the excel sheet into a dataset, and the export would do the opposite, from the dataset to the excel file
the excel file/book could contain more than one sheet
(preferably not through oledb)

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check, EPPLus for .XLSX files and NPOI for .xls file. There are many. ExcelReader for reading both format and return a datatable.

Comment: I found code using oledb to do that, but when i tried it, it didn't work. something with microsoft.jet.oledb4.0 not being on my machine

Comment: If you are using office 2007 or later you could have a look at openxml and the openxml sdk.  I have imported and exported data this way in the past.  There is a bit of a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with it, but there is an API for this already. Have you looked at [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx)? From the link I just sent you, it looks like there is just about all the functionality you could want.